# Compiler Error C2440 IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 cant be used to initialize an entity of type IMAGE_NT_HEADERS

Tags: c++, initialization

So im writing a .dll for an injection, i ran into this problem and i have no clue abt how to fix tiError    C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 *' to 'const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *'  mod C:\Users\user\source\repos\mod\mod\Pattern.cpp  21

the code im using here:

```
const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* ntHeader = reinterpret_cast<const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64*>(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(dosHeader) + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Why do you expect these two types to be the same?

Comment: Try `const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64* ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign a `const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64*` to a `const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*`.  They are not the same type.

Either cast the adjusted pointer to `const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*`, or declare `ntHeader` as `const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64*`.